# Fatal Error on only 1 Product Page

Tags: layout, error, xml

As the title states, I seem to have a single product (simple product, visiblity "catalog/search", In Stock) that I am unable to access. I have more than 1,000 other products with no issues.

I changed the URL path of the product, reindexed all data, flushed/refreshed the cache, and got the same Fatal Error.

This is all the product page displays:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object in 
/var/www/sites/storename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 154
```

Layout.php line 154:

```
public function generateXml()
    {
        $xml = $this->getUpdate()->asSimplexml();
        $removeInstructions = $xml->xpath("//remove");
        ...
```

This leads me to believe there is an issue in one of my .xml files' `remove` block statements, but I have no idea where to begin looking.

Comment: check the layout update xml field in the product edit form. it might not be a valid xml

Comment: World record... I feel ashamed for missing that. Submit as an answer and I'll gladly accept it. There was some random html/description content in the **Product Edit > Design > Custom Layout Update** area. Removed that and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `Design > Custom Layout Update` field in the product edit form.
Most probably is not a valid XML.

**Catalog > Manage Products > Edit Product**

[image: Backend View]

Comment: Yes,  you are right.  I just had this issue and did check in xml layout section. because of wrong syntax it thrown an error.  Thanks it helped me!! Please keep doing this